# Make viewpagerindicator appear at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have implemented viewpagerindicator in my activity but the problem they always appear at the top, i wanted to make them appear at the bottom for this i have tried this layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<com.ugurtekbas.fadingindicatorlibrary.FadingIndicator
    android:id="@+id/circleIndicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:radius="5dp"
    app:fillColor="#2c70d6"
    app:strokeColor="#f7f4f2"
    app:shape="@string/shape_circle"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now this doesn't work unless i define a number to `viewpager height`. And if i use this layout viewpagerindicator appear just fine, but they appear at the top.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<com.ugurtekbas.fadingindicatorlibrary.FadingIndicator
    android:id="@+id/circleIndicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   //layout_below is gone
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:radius="5dp"
    app:fillColor="#2c70d6"
    app:strokeColor="#f7f4f2"
    app:shape="@string/shape_circle"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What i want is that to make viewpagerindicator appear on viewpager, not below `viewpager` taking extra-space on screen.

Comment: have you tried android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in FadingIndicator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:layout_alignBottom` instead of `android:layout_below`

Change your code to:

```
    <com.ugurtekbas.fadingindicatorlibrary.FadingIndicator
    android:id="@+id/circleIndicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pager"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:radius="5dp"
    app:fillColor="#2c70d6"
    app:strokeColor="#f7f4f2"
    app:shape="@string/shape_circle"

    />
```